# Qt platform windows plugin error

Tags: qt

I trying to run app from this link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/editor4sumo/
but i'm getting error: This application failed to start beacuse it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
I read all topic about this problem on Stack Overflow but nothing solved my problem. I added libEGL.dll, libGLEd.dll but it still don't work. Do you have any other ideas, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

In the folder where your executable is located add a new folder called `platforms` and put `qwindows.dll` into that. The platform plugin is probably located at: `Qt\version\msvc20XX\plugins\platforms`.

Comment: I made it too. As i said i tried all what was posted on StackOverflow

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski Have you checked the dependencies with the dependency walker? Are you sure you have the dll in the platforms folder? Have you added the `icuXXYY.dll` (icudt30.dll for example) files?

Comment: I didn't know this tool. So i used it and i get this errors http://i.imgur.com/4Q6oahO.png icuxyy.dll files was added before.

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski The ones you are getting are warnings, there should be things below those that appear in red (if you added everything it might be 64 bit dll's when it needs 32 bit or the other way around)

Comment: Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski Exactly what I thought, some or all of your dll's don't match the architecture required by the executable (64 bit dll's and 32 bit dll's are mixed up). The dependency walker should show you which these are (in red x86/x64).

Comment: So if i have in red x64 it should be x86 ?

Comment: I'm running computer with win 32bit and will try execute it there.

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski The problem is not the computer you run it on, it is that some of the dll's you are using are 64 bit instead of the required 32 bit dll's (replace these dll's with the 32 bit version).

Comment: But even i copied all files from the link once time more dependency walkers shows that 90% of dlls are from bad architecture. Developer gave bad dlls?

Comment: When i checked it on dependency walker on win 32 bit i don't have this dll with red x64. It still don't starts but walker shows only 2 warnings: 
 Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found. Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
And previous file errors showed here:  i.imgur.com/4Q6oahO.png

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski Those warnings can normally be ignored if the process handles it. It starts with an error or does it not start at all?

Comment: @FlorisVeeleman It's still not start wtih the same error: This application failed to start beacuse it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski Afraid not :L

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski I am getting the exact warnings you are getting and my program works, I have no idea.

Comment: YOu getting error on start and it works or only this errors in dependency walker?

Comment: @KrzysiekNowakowski I'm getting the same errors in dependency walkers and the executable works without errors.

Comment: I got start error on 2 computers. Could you tell me what excatlly you did after download?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61348/discussion-on-answer-by-floris-velleman-qt-platform-windows-plugin-error).